# Keep id order as in query

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I'm using elasticsearch to get a mapping of ids to some values, but it is crucial that I keep the order of the results in the order that the ids have.

Example:

```
  def term_mapping(ids)
    ids = ids.split(',')
    self.search do |s|
      s.filter :terms, id: ids
    end
  end

  res = term_mapping("4,2,3,1")
```

The result collection should contain the objects with the ids in order 4,2,3,1...

Do you have any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use search you can sort ids before you send them to elasticsearch and retrive results sorted by id, or you can create a custom sort script that will return the position of the current document in the array of ids. However, a simpler and faster solution would be to simply use [Multi-Get](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/multi-get.html) instead of search.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I guess Multi-Get is not supported by tire yet. I will stick to my simple ruby based solution till then...

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [Multi GET API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-get.html). If this doesn't work for you, another solution is to sort the results after you retrieve them from es. In python, this can be done this way:

```
doc_ids = ["123", "333", "456"]  # We want to keep this order
order = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(doc_ids)} 
es_results = [{"_id": "333"}, {"_id": "456"}, {"_id": "123"}]
results = sorted(es_results, key=lambda x: order[x['_id']])
# Results:
# [{'_id': '123'}, {'_id': '333'}, {'_id': '456'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this problem is resolved,, but someone will help with this answer

we can used the `pinned_query` for the ES. Do not need the loop for the sort the order

```
**qs = {
      "size" => drug_ids.count,
      "query" => {
        "pinned" => {
          "ids" => drug_ids,
          "organic" => {
              "terms": {
                "id": drug_ids
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }**
```

It will keep the sequence of the input as it